# How to solve A facade root has not been set. In Facade.php line 236: Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I am receiving 
`In Facade.php line 236: A facade root has not been set.`
in a Laravel 5.8 project I am cloning from GitLab. 
here is the log output

````
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\Users\\Abdellah Ramadan\\Desktop\\COMPANY\\poblysh\\config\\seotools.php(14): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('get', Array)
#1 C:\\Users\\Abdellah Ramadan\\Desktop\\COMPANY\\poblysh\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration.php(72): require('C:\\\\Users\\\\Abdell...')
#2 C:\\Users\\Abdellah Ramadan\\Desktop\\COMPANY\\poblysh\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository))
#3 C:\\Users\\Abdellah Ramadan\\Desktop\\COMPANY\\poblysh\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(210): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#4 C:\\Users\\Abdellah Ramadan\\Desktop\\COMPANY\\poblysh\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(322): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#5 C:\\Users\\Abdellah Ramadan\\Desktop\\COMPANY\\poblysh\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(131): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#6 C:\\Users\\Abdellah Ramadan\\Desktop\\COMPANY\\poblysh\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#7 {main}
"} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run composer install ?? `composer install`

Comment: Do you use vagrant homestead ?

Comment: No, I'm not. I will be serving using artisan

Comment: you can open your terminal and  run command inside project directory `php artisan cache:clear` , `php artisan config:clear`, `composer dump-autoload`. Let me know if worked

Comment: Yes those commands are still spitting the same error. None of the artisan command is running.